# Why is user name not highlighted in nomination comments before loading additional comments?

Tags: bug, comments, design, moderator-election

Today while I was reading comments at [the moderator election page](//stackoverflow.com/election) I noticed the name of the writer of an answer is not highlighted until I click **Show more comments**:

**Before:**

[image]

**After:**

[image]

Is this an expected behaviour? Looked like a bug to me.

Note: Tried with Chrome and Firefox, same behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, the `owner` class responsible for the background isn't set on the owner's comments, unless the comments are expanded:

[image]

When the comments are expanded, the `owner` class is added, and the link to the user's profile is highlighted:

[image]